# xpath for accessing JS generated class instance

Tags: xpath, webdriver

I need to use xpath as a locator for Selenium Webdriver to click on a button.  It is in a dialog that is dynamically generated.  Firebug/firepath gives div references with numbers that will change.  I've read a lot of great tips here and am close but can't seem to get the exact specification. I need xpath to access Close and Cancel:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all 
ui-button-text-only  ui-state-hover" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Close</span>
</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Create</span>
```

No success with either:

```
    xpath="//*[@class='ui-button-text' and @value='Close'") 
    xpath="//span[contains(@class='ui-button-text' and @value='Close')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//span[@class = 'ui-button-text' and . = 'Close']
```

These selects all `span` elements in the XML document, with string value `"Close"` and the string value of whose `class` attribute is `"ui-button-text"` .

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm no longer getting invalid xpath error but it still can't access the element.  It looks like it is because there are multiple dialogs with that class and close although only one is active.  I'm trying to add something like: //[@class='ui-dialog'][style:display()!='none'] before the span...if I get the syntax correct will this work?  Other suggestions?

Comment: @user1083649: Is `style:sisplay()` an extension function that is made available to the XPath engine? If not (which I guess is the case), then you will get a corresponding error due to this. You *must* be able to uniquely identify the element you want selected using just its properties and relationships in the XML document only -- otherwise you don't know what you are asking...

Comment: Thanks again - the extension function is not available and your note put me back on the right track.  I ended up using a sibling to get to the right area: xpath="//div[@id='about-app-dialog']/../div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix']/button/span[@class = 'ui-button-text' and . = 'OK']"

Answer (score 0):

Use @Dimitre's expression:

```
//span[@class='ui-button-text' and .='Close']
```

I'm answering to explain where you went wrong with your original expressions.

**First expression**:

```
//*[@class='ui-button-text' and @value='Close'")]
```

This selects all elements (`*`) anywhere in the document (`//`) that have an attribute (`@`) named `class` whose value is `ui-button-text` and an attribute named `value` whose value is `Close`. The attribute axis specifier is the `@` symbol. This is short for `attribute::`. The following expressions are equivalent:

```
//*[@class='ui-button-text' and @value='Close'")]
//*[attribute::class='ui-button-text' and attribute::value='Close'")]
```

The above expressions can be fully expanded to:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*[attribute::class='ui-button-text' and 
                                     attribute::value='Close'")]
```

In short: try to understand XPath's **syntactic abbreviations** when constructing expressions.

**Second expression**:

```
//span[contains(@class='ui-button-text' and @value='Close')]
```

The XPath [`contains` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) has the following signature:

```
boolean contains(string, string)
```

...and is described in the spec like this:

> The contains function returns true if the first argument string
>   contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false.

You seem to be trying to treat it as a more general, magic function that checks whether the element "contains" some attributes, but it is fundamentally a *string* function.

I recommend a quick (or not so quick) read of the XPath 1.0 Recommendation:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Until then you'll just be guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I've read the xpath recommendations but clearly am struggling to put this into practice.  Unfortunately even the "correct" expression is not giving me a hook into the web element.  I think it must be hitting a different dialog button that is inactive and I need to add a parent to the path such that it will get the class whose display is not none before the specification Dimitre helped with.  Something like xpath="//[@class='ui-dialog'][style:display()!='none'] prior to the span(@class).  Does that sound on the right track?